# How can i add a new entry into a mysql table, BUT only for 1 column, while keeping all other column data

Tags: mysql

So i have the following table

[image: table1]

but when i run the following command:

```
"INSERT INTO default_db.loader_messages (confirmation_secure_radio_button_message) VALUES ('$confirmmessagevalue1')";
```

it adds a new row, but empties the loader_message1 column as you can see above.

please tell me how do i keep the current data in the loader_message1 column as well as add a new row ?

Comment: Do not post images of tables. Paste the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements into the question.

Comment: how do i ensure that the default values of loader_message1 is th previous value?

Comment: Your Insert is working fine. You have only one column name within insert (which had replaced values) and hence the other column is empty.

If you really want the value of row id 7 to be duplicated to further rows...it is a poor design. You need to redesign your database / script. Please describe your actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change from an insert..values to insert..select then you could

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int auto_increment primary key,col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10));
insert into t (col1) values ('col1');
insert into t (col1,col2) 
    select col1,'aaa'
    from t where id = (select max(id) from t)
;
insert into t (col1) values ('xxx');
insert into t (col1,col2) 
    select col1,'bbb'
    from t where id = (select max(id) from t)
;

select * from t;

+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | col1 | NULL |
|  2 | col1 | aaa  |
|  3 | xxx  | NULL |
|  4 | xxx  | bbb  |
+----+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

if this is not a possibility for you then consider capturing in your front end before inserting or inserting in a procedure and fill down after the insert using an update.

Comment: Please can you tell me how your example can be adapted to my table using the variables in my example as im not familiar with sql commands.

All i want to do is add a value for the "confirmation_secure_radio_button_message" column as a new row, while keeping all the values from the other columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned that it is a poor design to replicate column value to multiple rows.

Still...you shall

```
select loader_message1 from dbname where yourcondition;
```

get the mysqli result into $row and then using

```
$row['loader_message1'] or $row[0]
```

in the insert like

```
insert... (fld1, fld2) values (value1, value2)
```